# undefined is not a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
Promise(promise2).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

the `Promise.all` shows the result "Array [3, 42, "foo"]" but the `Promise` gave me an error "undefined is not a promise"
i tried to edit it as `new Promise` but it gave me a new error "Promise resolver 42 is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it like this:

```
Promise.resolve(promise2).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Promise constructor is used to wrap function and not integer which is why you are getting an error when trying to warp a integer inside a promise. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise)

You can do this in two ways:-

1. Create a Promise resolved like you have done in `promise1`

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(42);
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
promise2.then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

2. You can wrap integer value inside a new promise and then use that value

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(42);
}).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```